# APFS RAID mirror - can it be done, and anyone have experience?

Tags: macos, apfs, disk-format, raid

So I've moved most of the server functions off my trusty Mac Mini 2012, and am looking to set it back up as my desktop driver for the time being. When running macOS off external drives with none of the VMs and disk heavy network services, it is surprisingly responsive for such an old system. I'm a little proud of it!

Anyway, part of planning to do this I decided to pop a pair of SSDs in it to replace the single SSD that has been marching along, and already picked up a pair of drives and the second SATA cable I'll need.

I'm finally at the point where I'm almost ready to do the surgery and get reinstalling, and went looking for how to build a mirror in APFS (since it will be a read-heavy lifestyle from here on), but have been unable to find much.

There are a few forum posts about using appleRAID and putting APFS on top of that, and at least one AskDifferent post talking about a similar system failing to boot, although that was with RAID0. Nothing more recent than a couple of years.

I'm wondering if anyone knows if it is indeed possible to make an APFS container comprised of multiple disks directly, and set them as a mirror. The `diskutil` docs mention you can make a container with more than one physical disk backing it, but go on to discuss how to determine performance roles for it to be a Fusion Drive.

Alternately, does anyone have any experience with backing an APFS Container with an appleRAID mirror? Boot issues, reliability issues, anything like that to report?